# How to get a list of loaded run time packages?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, runtime-packages

I'm creating a "Version Info" dialog box for my applications; something similar to the one Delphi has in the "About" dialog box. I'd like to display the version information only for the run time packages (`.BPL` files), and not all the loaded DLLs. Does the `RTL` include functions to get a list of the loaded packages, or I have to use the [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and filter the result?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [EnumModules](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.EnumModules) function from `System`.

Here's a very simple demonstration of how to use the `EnumModules` function and get the names of all the loaded `BPL's`. It's a console application, but the code can be easily reused in a production application. If you want to test it out, make sure you're using packages:

```
program Project17;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows;

function EnumModulesFunc(HInstance: Integer; Data: Pointer): Boolean;
var Buff:array[0..1023] of char;
begin
  if GetModuleFileName(HInstance, @Buff, SizeOf(Buff)) = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
    Buff[High(Buff)] := #0;
  TStringList(Data).Add(Buff);
end;

var L: TStringList;

begin
  try
    L := TStringList.Create;
    try
      System.EnumModules(EnumModulesFunc, L);
      WriteLn(L.Text);
    finally L.Free;
    end;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```